# Can someone please help me identify this aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I apologize for the image quality as it is a picture of an image on a television screen.  I was watching an episode of American pickers at the time and the model of the plane was not discussed.  Can anyone identify this aircraft?  I am not sure I have seen a configuration like it before.
[image: photograph of aircraft shown on television]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks a lot like a [Curtiss Model D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtiss_Model_D) to me.